# Grunt: Bower for development and CDN for production - is it possible?

Tags: gruntjs, bower

For development, I guess it is fine to use a plugin like https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep

But for production I would like to use CDN where such exists. Does it exist a Grunt plugin that goes through the bower.json file and replaces this with a CDN-link from the most popular ones (and if a component is present in more than one CDN, then pick one based on rank-setting or random or something).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but this might be helpful - https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-google-cdn

If you'd like to use a different cdn, then maybe you could use [cdnify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cdnify)

Comment: None of these are real help, since (correct me if I am mistaken), both of them handles just one cdn. First handles google-cdn and second handles one cdn that you define. I am using components that uses various cdns. If all components had agreed upon one cdn than everything would be ok. If either of the grunt plugins you mentioned allowed for multiple cdn definition, and then automatically would go through that list of cdns to check if a certain component where present and pick the first one it finds, then I would be happy :)

Comment: See [bower issue #19](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/19#issuecomment-22069247). The issue was closed with some general guidelines for doing what you want. I'm not aware of something that actually do it. Maybe you can tailor something with https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-local2cdn

Comment: That was an interesting read, @liorchaga, I have been under the assumption that using a cdn is better than servicing the files myself. Maybe this is not the case and I do not need to use a cdn after all... Thanks for the link.

Comment: CDN has many advantages when it comes to browser performance - optimized cache policies, splitting your browser requests to several domains which results in fetching more resources concurrently, etc.
So wouldn't disqualify CDN altogether.